# Postgres SQL select a range of records spaced out by a given interval

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to determine if it is possible, using only sql for postgres, to select a range of time ordered records at a given interval.

Lets say I have 60 records, one record for each minute in a given hour.  I want to select records at 5 minute intervals for that hour.  The resulting rows should be 12 records each one 5 minutes apart.

This is currently accomplished by selecting the full range of records and then looping thru the results and pulling out the records at the given interval.  I am trying to see if I can do this purly in sql as our db is large and we may be dealing with tens of thousands of records.

Any thoughts?

Comment: please show your accomplishment - maybe it will make your question more clear

Answer (score 8):

Yes you can. Its really easy once you get the hang of it. I think its one of jewels of SQL and its especially easy in PostgreSQL because of its excellent temporal support. Often, complex functions can turn into very simple queries in SQL that can scale and be indexed properly.

This uses generate_series to draw up sample time stamps that are spaced 1 minute apart. The outer query then extracts the minute and uses modulo to find the values that are 5 minutes apart.

```
select
    ts,
    extract(minute from ts)::integer as minute

    from
    ( -- generate some time stamps - one minute apart
        select
            current_time + (n || ' minute')::interval  as ts
        from generate_series(1, 30) as n
    ) as timestamps
    -- extract the minute check if its on a 5 minute interval
    where extract(minute from ts)::integer % 5 = 0
    -- only pick this hour 
    and extract(hour from ts) = extract(hour from current_time)
;
         ts         | minute 
--------------------+--------
 19:40:53.508836-07 |     40
 19:45:53.508836-07 |     45
 19:50:53.508836-07 |     50
 19:55:53.508836-07 |     55
```

Notice how you could add an computed index on the where clause (where the value of the expression would make up the index) could lead to major speed improvements. Maybe not very selective in this case, but good to be aware of.

I wrote a reservation system once in PostgreSQL (which had lots of temporal logic where date intervals could not overlap) and never had to resort to iterative methods.

[http://www.amazon.com/SQL-Design-Patterns-Programming-Focus/dp/0977671542](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0977671542) is an excellent book that goes has lots of interval examples. Hard to find in book stores now but well worth it.

Comment: I think the question is something like a GPS feed, where we want to extract one data point per 5 minute interval.

Comment: Which version of PostgreSQL is required for this functionality?

Answer (score 3):

Extract the minutes, convert to int4, and see, if the remainder from dividing by 5 is 0:

```
select * 
  from TABLE 
  where int4 (date_part ('minute', COLUMN)) % 5 = 0;
```

Comment: This is very close to what I have come up with as a solution.  In reality the records are coming in once a second or faster and the spacing of the records is determined at run time.  Currently I am doing something like this:  

CAST (extract(epoch from date_trunc('second', search_time)) AS integer) % 300 = 0

Comment: Can only edit for 5 minutes...  lemme try that again.

I am still determining which of these suits my needs.. thank you for the reply.  This is very close to what I had come up with as a possible solution.  My records are stored once a second or faster and the spacing of the records is determined at run time.  Currently I am doing something like this:

Comment: select *
from table
where id = 'record_id'
and CAST (extract(epoch from date_trunc('second', the_time)) AS integer) % 300 = 0
order by the_time

The 300 in this case returns records on 5 minute increments but in some cases I am looking for 10 second increments or 15 minute increments.

The downside to this as indicated by someone above is that the records are returned based 'on the fives'.

Comment: Where is the problem, I don't get it? Two reportings for the same second? Changing from 5 to 10 to 15 s (why)?

Comment: Well I round to seconds essentially because if I round to minutes I will have 60 or more records with the same minute, or 60 records each time % 5 = 0.   Rounding to the second gives me rounded but pretty unique results and % 300 gives me the expected one record for every 5 minutes.   However, as someone else mentioned, the records are on even '5' times.  For example: If I am looking for five minute records in a time range from 1:03 and 1:18 this solution will give me 1:05, 1:10 and 1:15.  But I'd want 1:03, 1:08 and 1:13.

Comment: If you like to get results with offset 3 to the 5 minutes, use `... % 5 = 3;`

Comment: that may be an option..  though I was looking to just get five minutes from the starting point..  calculating that value may work though.  still investigating.  thanks.

Comment: You can do a subquery for the starting value, found with MIN(...) of something.

Answer (score 1):

- If the intervals are not time based, and you just want every 5th row; or
- If the times are regular and you **always** have one record per minute

The below gives you one record per every 5

```
select *
from
(
  select *, row_number() over (order by timecolumn) as rown
  from tbl
) X
where mod(rown, 5) = 1
```

If your time records are not regular, then you need to generate a time series (given in another answer) and left join that into your table, group by the time column (from the series) and pick the MAX time from your table that is less than the time column.

Pseudo

```
select thetimeinterval, max(timecolumn)
from ( < the time series subquery > ) X
left join tbl on tbl.timecolumn <= thetimeinterval
group by thetimeinterval
```

And further join it back to the table for the full record (assuming unique times)

```
select t.* from
tbl inner join
(
    select thetimeinterval, max(timecolumn) timecolumn
    from ( < the time series subquery > ) X
    left join tbl on tbl.timecolumn <= thetimeinterval
    group by thetimeinterval
) y on tbl.timecolumn = y.timecolumn
```

Comment: You would generate the overhead of windowing functions needlessly. If the condition is about time then is no reason to add any more information. It also has the requirement that all data exists and there is never a missing row which may not be the case. Probably best just to answer the question with what is given.

Comment: @nate But I am solving the question where your answer does nothing towards selecting 12 of 60 per-minute records at 5 minute intervals. You're only building a time series.

Comment: Thanks Richard. In my case the intervals are time based but they may be much faster than one per minute.   In production they will be one per second and there is no guarantee that there might not be two for a given second.   I will be looking into several of these solutions including the option to just select every 5th row.  I just tested it out and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
select min(ts), extract(minute from ts)::integer / 5 
   as bucket group by bucket order by bucket;
```

This has the advantage of doing the right thing if you have two readings for the same minute, or your readings skip a minute. Instead of using `min` even better would be to use one of the the `first`() aggregate functions-- code for which you can find here:

http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/First_%28aggregate%29

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that your five minute intervals are "on the fives", so to speak. That is, that you want 07:00, 07:05, 07:10, not 07:02, 07:07, 07:12. It also assumes you don't have two rows within the same minute, which might not be a safe assumption.

```
select your_timestamp
from your_table
where cast(extract(minute from your_timestamp) as integer) in (0,5);
```

If you might have two rows with timestamps within the same minute, like

```
2011-01-01 07:00:02
2011-01-01 07:00:59
```

then this version is safer.

```
select min(your_timestamp)
from your_table
group by (cast(extract(minute from your_timestamp) as integer) / 5)
```

Wrap either of those in a view, and you can join it to your base table.